# Boto3 get input from step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

I have a fargate task running a python script which works fine. However, occasionally, I want to pass in some custom configuration to the step function. The only approach I have found so far is through boto3 first listing all running executions and after which I describe the running step function.

Even though this works, it does have some limitations. I would rather be able to describe the actual running task (step/stage) instead of describing the entire step function. Is this possible? Perhaps there is a better way of doing it.

I know it is possible to pass in environmental variables through ContainerOverrides. I find that solution a bit clunky though.

Current solution:

```
def list_executions():
    stfn = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
    response = stfn.list_executions(
        stateMachineArn='ARN',
        statusFilter='RUNNING',
        maxResults=123,
    )
    # CODE TO EXTRACT executionArn
    return executionArn
    print(f"RESP: {response}")


def step_input(executionArn):
    stfn = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
    response = stfn.describe_execution(
        executionArn=executionArn,
    )
    # CODE TO EXTRACT INPUT
    return input


executionArn = step_input()
input = list_executions(executionArn)
```

Comment: Fargate tasks to run python, why not use Lamda function. You can use SAM for step function.

Comment: I am running a script that takes several hours, exceeding the lambda timeout limitation.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to access the input parameter without having to loop through all of the executions first?